# What is a good design pattern for DB manager that provides Session object in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, design-patterns

I'm developing a class that provides a session to any consumer. So, the class is responsible of getting a SessionFactory and opening up a session and passing it whenever needed.

So, What is a better design? 
Static method in a class like this?

```
public class DbStatIo {
     private static SessionFactory factory=null;

    public static Session getSessionForStatDb(){
        if (factory==null){
            SessionFactory factory=new Configuration()
            .configure(FilesManager.getSenseiConfigForStatDb())
            .buildSessionFactory();
        }
        return factory.openSession();
    }

}
```

or just a local public function? Or something else?

Comment: If you are in web environment you may be interested in the Open Session In View pattern https://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessionInView?_sscc=t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The creation of a `SessionFactory` instance is a very expensive operation due to the amount of information it holds (as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14411979/1250033)); since it is thread-safe, having a single instance (as a singleton) or keeping a static reference should be sufficient.

However, using it as a singleton might give you better, more flexible control over the lifetime of the object than storing it as a field in static class. You can have a dependency on your data access objects to a `IDatabaseService`, exposing a method `getSession`, implemented by a single instance of `HibernateService`.