# LazyFutureStream and multiple thread persistence

Tags: hibernate, java-8, cyclops-react

I am using [simple-react](https://github.com/aol/simple-react).

Inside `LazyFutureStream` I want to persist the entity .

```
LazyFutureStream.parallel(1,2,3,4,5)
       .map(id -> {
            try {
                SessionFactory sessionFactory = Application.getHibernateBundle()
                                                           .getSessionFactory();
                ManagedSessionContext.bind(sessionFactory.openSession());
                Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
                session.beginTransaction();

                Model model = new Model(sessionFactory);
                model.persist(id);
                session.getTransaction().commit();
            }
        });
```

Is this correct ? Is there any way i can skip session factory creation for every thread .

ALSO in above I only want to fork but not join. Is that fine?

Comment: No, this is not correct. Your `try` block lacks a `catch` or `finally`. Besides that, `map` operations are usually supposed to *map* from one item/value to another, hence the associated function must return a value. If you just want to consume items, `forEach` may be the way to go. And if you don’t want to create a new Session for each item, move its creation code out of the lambda expression.

Comment: if i move the Session out , then it will be shared one, Will that lead to some issues regarding thread concurrency

Comment: I don’t know enough about hibernate to say something about thread safety of the `Session` class. But in case it’s not, you can always wrap a supplier of a non thread safe component into a `ThreadLocal`. That way, you are safe having one per thread, but still skip the creation for items processed by the same worker thread. But maybe someone will come up with a definite answer regarding the thread safety of a `Session`. In the meanwhile, you could try searching for an answer in its documentation…

Comment: You mean is that threadLocal.set(session) will make the session object exclusive to it . similar for all other thread , . Same session object will be replicated for each thread if set on thread local

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of simple-react, while I'm definitely not an expert on Hibernate's SessionFactory, these Stackoverflow posts does suggest it is safe to share them across threads however.

- [Why use only one SessionFactory Object per application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411860/why-use-only-one-sessionfactory-object-per-application)
- [Reasons why Hibernate's sessionFactory is thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14259652/reasons-why-hibernates-sessionfactory-is-thread-safe)

**Optimizing your Stream**

LazyFutureStream.parallel uses the Common ForkJoinPool (the same as standard Java 8 parallel Streams). So, if you are using these elsewhere in your application (particularly for CPU Bound tasks), they will compete with your blocking I/O.

**LazyReact StreamBuilder**

You can use the LazyReact Stream Builder to set up a Stream builder that uses a custom thread pool (and do resuse the builder, the JVM doesn't do a great job of Garbage Collecting Thread pools).

To setup a Stream builder with a thread pool of 10 threads, and that allows 10 active Futures -

```
    LazyReact streamBuilder = new LazyReact(10,10);
```

**Creating your stream**

As Holger suggested you can use forEach (this is efficient on simple-react v0.99.x and above, on previous versions a peek / run combo will perform better)

```
   streamBuilder.of(1,2,3,4,5)
                 .forEach(id-> { //do work here });
```

This will execute on your thread pool, but will block the current thread until the work completes.

For a non-blocking alternative you can use run() with peek.

```
   streamBuilder.of(1,2,3,4,5)
                 .peek(id-> { //do work here })
                 .run();
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Tagir!